# Import .htaccess rules in IIS using command line

Tags: iis-7, iis

Is it possible to import /convert the .htaccess file to web.config using command line ( NOT using GUI) and how ?

If it is not directly possible is there any workaround for this ?

note : http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules/ here is the way to do it using IIS GUI ,which I cant do.

Thanks, Sourabh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an import tool from the command line.

What's the reason why you can't do this from the IIS GUI?  If you don't have access to the server with the GUI, you can perform the import on another computer ... for example your workstation, or grab a machine for an hour from [Vaasnet](http://www.vaasnet.com).

Once you have them imported then you can xcopy the config to the server.

Comment: Repeating the clear+import+apply process during dev/testing brings on a kind of mental RSI. This is why scripts are good and GUIs are not.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/01/how-do-i-script-automate-iis7-configuration.aspx

It looks like this tool should allow you to automate the configuration of URL Rewrite 2.0